# SQLite JDBC in Java Web App Servlet

Tags: java, sqlite, servlets, jdbc, in-memory-database

I am relatively new to developing web apps and I am currently working on a Java servlet web application and have need for a temporary database to store output from a method while it is running in scope.  Once the method is completed, I will query the database to retrieve the results I need and then return it back to the servlet to be served up in the web page.  Since there will be a lot of i/o from the database and there is no need to persist the database once the method is completed, I am thinking that a light-weight DB like SQLite JDBC will work best.  https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads

Here is the code I am planning on using to instantiate the database:

```
Connection c = null;
    try {
      Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
      c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
      System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
      System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
```

Question: Can SQLite be run like this where a database is instantiated while the method is in scope and then is erased once the method goes out of scope once the method and thread is completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declan,

You are creating an external resource, which is a connection to a database. You are responsible for closing the resource before you return from the method. Luckily Java provides a good way to do this, using [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). You can do something like:

`Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
try (final Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");) {
  // ... write and read from the database
} catch ( Exception e ) {
  System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
  // -- do not exit yet: System.exit(0);
}
// ... don't forget to delete test.db`

Also, since this is a servlet, you may have multiple threads creating a file with the same name. See if you can find a way to uniquely name the database file.

Sualeh.

Comment: Thanks Sualeh.  If I am understanding correctly, if test.db doesn't exist until this method is run, will SQLite instantiate the database?

Comment: Yes, SQLite instantiate the database. However, remember to delete the database file after you are done.

Comment: Also, take a look at how to create an in-memory connection on https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/overview. You still need to close the connection, though, as explained above.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  Since the database is instantiated when the connection is established, how do I assign the database to an object so that I can then call the delete method?

Comment: If you use the in-memory connection (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::memory:");), you do not need to "delete" anything at all!

Comment: Right, that is perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!